# Under what conditions does Safari have access to the Keychain?

Tags: passwords, password-management, macos, ios, keychain

The Keychain is shared among many different apple products and includes asymmetric, symmetric, and other types of security data.

People who use iCloud, and also enable the keychain synchronization allows for many (all?) secrets to be copied from their OSX computer to iOS.

I haven't yet been able to figure out how an iOS app can get access to all passwords on a device, but I do see that Safari mobile has the ability to share passwords with the Safari desktop.

**Question**

- When I [add a password to the keychain,](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Value_Type_Keys) what configuration, permissions, etc are necessary to expose that data to Safari?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm saving credentials to the keychain that should only be read by my signed application, and should not be read by any extension, plugin, etc that isn't produced by me.

In other words, I am concerned that private key data can be exposed by the auto population feature of Safari's username and password courtesy feature.